# Parse command string with nested quotes into arguments and flags

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, parsing, command

I'm trying to create a command parser for a Discord bot for when it receives a message, but I am having issues with dealing with nested quotes. I have made it so that it can parse a string with double quotes and flags, but it does not handle nested quotes.

#### Here are my requirements:

- Handle double quotes.
- Handle nested double quotes.
- Handle flags (can be anywhere after `!command`).

  - A flag without a specified value defaults to a value of `true`/`1`.

For example, the following string:

```sh
!command that --can "handle double" quotes "and \"nested double\" quotes" --as --well=as --flags="with values"
```

...should result in the following arguments: `command`, `that`, `handle double`, `quotes`, `and "nested double" quotes` and the following flags: `"can": true`, `"as": true`, `"well": "as"`, `"flags": "with values"`.

#### Here is what I have so far:

```js
// splits up the string into separate arguments and flags
const parts = content.slice(1).trim().match(/(--\w+=)?"[^"]*"|[^ "]+/g)
  .map(arg => arg.replace(/^"(.*)"$/, '$1'));

// separates the arguments and flags
const [ args, flags ] = parts.reduce((parts, part) => {
  // check if flag or argument
  if (part.startsWith('--')) {
    // check if has a specified value or not
    if (part.includes('=')) {
      // parses the specified value
      part = part.split('=');
      const value = part.slice(1)[0];

      parts[1][part[0].slice(2)] = value.replace(/^"(.*)"$/, '$1');
    } else {
      parts[1][part.slice(2)] = true;
    }
  } else {
    parts[0].push(part);
  }

  return parts;
}, [[], {}]);
```

This currently parses into the following arguments: `command`, `that`, `handle double`, `quotes`, `and \`, `nested`, `double\`,  `quotes` and the following flags: `"can": true`, `"as": true`, `"well": "as"`, `"flags": "with values"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the first RegEx to allow `\"` in the middle of quoted values. The following line:

```js
const parts = content.slice(1).trim().match(/(--\w+=)?"[^"]*"|[^ "]+/g)
```

...changed to:

```js
const parts = content.slice(1).trim().match(/(--\S+=)?"(\\"|[^"])*"|[^ "]+/g)
```

#### Modifications

- The `"[^"]*"` section was changed to `"(\\"|[^"])*"` to allow `\"` to validate, preventing the quoted value from being terminated by quotes with backslashes before them.
- I changed the `\w` in `(--\w+=)?` to a `\S` resulting in `(--\S+=)?` to allow more letters to validate.

Comment: This doesn't work generally. With the test input `cc -E -Dquote='"\""'   -c test.c`, the third matched group should be `-Dquote='"\""'`, but it is not. See https://regex101.com/r/mtDDNU/1 - I don't know how to fix your regex, or if it's fixable; just wanted to point out in case someone else considers this **wrong answer** as a solution

Comment: BTW, my counter example defines a preprocessor macro named `quote` which is a quoted string containing one character: the double quote (`"`)